# Linking python extension modules

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have two extension modules, imaginatively named `foo` and `bar`. `bar` consists of a C++ function and  a simple wrapper around it

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add_numbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int bar_add_numbers(int  a, int b)
{
    return add_numbers(a, b);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(_bar, m)
{
    m.def("add_numbers", &bar_add_numbers);
}
```

`foo` has an identical wrapper, but without the definition.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add_numbers(int,  int);

int foo_add_numbers(int a, int  b)
{
    return add_numbers(a,  b);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(_foo, m)
{
    m.def("add_numbers", &foo_add_numbers);
}
```

After building these with setuptools

```py
import os
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import pybind11

os.environ['CC'] = 'clang++'
os.environ['CXX'] = 'clang++'

libbar = Extension('foo._bar',
    sources = ['bar.cpp'],
    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++14'],
    include_dirs = [pybind11.get_include()]
)

libfoo = Extension('foo._foo',
    sources = ['foo.cpp'],
    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++14'],
    include_dirs = [pybind11.get_include()]
)


setup(name='foo',
    version='1.0.0',
    ext_modules = [libbar, libfoo]
)
```

my expectation (hope) was that, provided `foo._foo` was imported *after* `foo._bar`, then `add_numbers` should  be resolved correctly from either wrapper. This does seem to be the case on  OSX.

```py
>>> from foo import _bar
>>> from foo import _foo
>>>  _foo.add_numbers(40, 2)
42
```

However on an ubuntu box this fails with `undefined symbol: _Z11add_numbersii`. And just when I thought I might almost have a working knowledge of dynamic linking.

What do I need to do differently on linux (or more specifically debian-based distros) to get  this to work?

EDIT: output from `nm` for the two .so files is

```
$ nm _bar.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep "add_numbers"
0000000000004a50 T _Z11add_numbersii
0000000000004a60 T _Z15bar_add_numbersii
```

and

```
$ nm _foo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep "add_numbers"
                 U _Z11add_numbersii
00000000000048c0 T _Z15foo_add_numbersii
```

And fwiw the compiler flags are

```
clang++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

Comment: If you have the same name (e.g. "add_numbers") in two different but simultaneous libs, which one is the right to use?

Comment: `add_numbers` is only defined  once.

Comment: To be a bit clearer, the symbol `_Z11add_numbersii` is defined (in this case) in the extension module  `_bar.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. I expected that once the python interpreter had loaded that module, the function could be called from another extension module. This appears to work  on OSX, but not an ubuntu machine, and I  am a bit  lost  as  to what the difference might be.

Comment: Can you edit your question with `nm` output for that function in both `.so` files? I suspect this may be because of default visibility.

Comment: Done. I thought the same, but thought the default visibility  was public (though I am out of my depth here).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I found [this](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#providing-a-c-api-for-an-extension-module)  which says that _details of visibility depend on the operating system_. And describes how modules can provide a C api with capsules.